# Bounds for sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $A_1,...,A_M$ be random variables, not necessarily independent.

For each one of them I know that $P( A_i \geq a )\leq B_i, \quad i=1,2,...,M$.

How can I retrieve lower/upper bounds for $\displaystyle P\left( \sum_{i=1}^M w_i A_i \geq a\right) $, where $w_i$ weights that sum to 1? What if they are independent? Thanks!